# How to combine working copies in SVN 1.7?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, working-copy

I have several huge subdirectories of svn repository checked out on my computer,
and I want to reorganize into one sparse working copy of the whole repository trunk.

- working_copies

  - trunk         (checked out with --depth=immediates, )

    - doc         (empty)
    - test_data   (empty)
    - project1    (empty)
    - project2    (empty)
  - test_data    (checkout of trunk/test_data)
  - project1     (checkout of trunk/project1)

Is it possible to do so without checking out everything (several Gb data from a very remote server) ?

Before version 1.6, it was possible to replace .svn subdirectories of a sparse working copy with full ones, since the information was local.

In SVN 1.7, there is only one database at the root of each working copy, and I see no way to manipulate it without connecting to the server.  Are there any tools that can help organize working copies without re-downloading them?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to organize the file structure, I recommend you to use the <kbd>Repo Browser</kbd> command, move the files using the <kbd>Repo Browser</kbd> window and mimic the new directory organization into your local copy.

If everything is right, TortoiseSVN will just recompose the .svn headers without downloading files. Otherwise, Tortoise will download all the missing files. Be careful to organize the folder remotely and locally, using well-defined steps.